# Vue CLI create separate bundle for Vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Hi I want to initiate Vue application from separate project and import Vue components to it by another project. When working on I got an issue between multiple Vue instances . To solve that I'm trying to create separate bundle for Vue and try to initiate application on separate project by it which uses to create components. How to create separate bundle for Vue which can be used from different projects?

Answer (score 0):

Hi for reference any one. Inside webpackconfig under externals can define as Vue : ['Vue'].